# Lodash - Retrieve an array of values for all object properties

Tags: lodash

I have something like

```
const payload = [{'name':'john doe', 'company': 'abc', 'age': 35}, 
                 {'name':'jane doe', 'company': 'def', 'age': 36}]

_.map(users, "name") => ['john doe', 'jane doe']
_.map(users, "company") => ['abc', 'def']
```

I want to have one call to retrieve the name, company and age from the payload. I don't want to make 3 calls with the `map` function. How can I do this? Because my payload is huge with a lot of properties.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lodash, you can map the objects to their values, and unzip the result:

```js
const payload = [{'name':'john doe', 'company': 'abc', 'age': 35}, {'name':'jane doe', 'company': 'def', 'age': 36}];

const result = _(payload)
  .map(_.values) // map to value arrays
  .unzip() // unzip the arrays
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The same idea works without lodash by mapping the objects into value arrays, and then transposing the values using reduce:

```js
const payload = [{'name':'john doe', 'company': 'abc', 'age': 35}, {'name':'jane doe', 'company': 'def', 'age': 36}];

const result = payload
  .map(Object.values) // map to value arrays
  .reduce((t, arr) => { // transpose the arrays
    arr.forEach((v, i) => (t[i] || (t[i] = [])).push(v));
      
    return t;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) wrapped inside a [`lodash#partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) as the iteratee for [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map).

```
const result = _.map(payload, _.partial(_.pick, _, ['name', 'company']));
```

```js
const payload = [{
    'name': 'john doe',
    'company': 'abc',
    'age': 35
  },
  {
    'name': 'jane doe',
    'company': 'def',
    'age': 36
  }
];
  
const result = _.map(payload, _.partial(_.pick, _, ['name', 'company']));

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not get this to work. Even in the above snippet it does not show the right results.